# Tool to UI, Performance, Functionality testing for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for IOS mobile application

Tags: automated-testing, performance, iphone, ios

I am new to IOS mobile application testing, can anyone suggest me the automation tool for IOS mobile application, so that UI, functionality and performance test could be done with that. I tried with [FONEMONKEY](http://www.gorillalogic.com/monkeytalk) buts its payable for trailer, required tool must be free for trailer version.

Specification is: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, iPhone-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to UI testing for web applications, you can make use of selenium. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/ It will help you create automated tests as you can recrd your UI actions and them re-play them back at a later point of time. Now when we are doing the UI testing, what we can do is we can change the user agent in our web browser to simulate an android tablet, iphone, etc. You can have a look at User-Agent Switcher 2.0 Chrom Extension. So with the combination of the two you are good to go.

Now you can combine the User-agent, selenium, and TestNG [http://testng.org/doc/index.html]. TestNG will allow you to write automated code tests which can perform UI based actions [http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html]

For doing the performance testing, you can actually make use of progressive wait periods for the page to load once you click on links/submit button etc and find out which page is taking more time to render, etc. Finally you can have the total time taken for your test as estimation of the amount it will take for a real user to complete the various combination of pages.

Comment: One caveat, switching the User-Agent does not reliably render content the same way that using the browser on the device would, or potentially use the same JavaScript engine, and also would typically be a much different screen resolution.  These could cause issues ranging from minor layout differences to completely broken functionality.  This would be a good way to get you maybe 75% of the way, but you will still need some manual, on device testing.

Comment: Yes Sam, you are correct that all the things cannot be tested properly via User-Agent. I just provided it as an alternate solution since some time back I had to do Android/iPhone testing and no device was available for a couple of months for me to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my point of view on mobile testing. I'm an engineer at Neotys, editor of NeoLoad. NeoLoad is a load testing solution designed for web and  mobile applications to realistically simulate users activities and monitor servers behaviors.

First of all, mobile testing raises the need to perform different tests. On the device point of view, you can do unit testing, functional testing, and devices compatibility testing.

About performance, there are two levels:
- Device: You can easily pick up tools on internet or from device manufacturers to analyze CPU, battery, memory leaks, and network use of your application on a particular device.
- Overall application chain: Testing the performance of the application and the server is what NeoLoad is designed for.

To put in a nutshell, NeoLoad records the network dialog between your application and its front-end server and uses this to generate the same load from thousands or millions of users. In addition to providing you with the evolution of response times, you get insights about your server and the root causes of performance issues.

NeoLoad records are non-intrusive and you can record any application, either web or native, standard or customized, for any platform in any version.

Also, NeoLoad allows you to [realistically simulate mobile networks](http://www.neotys.com/product/network-emulation.html) (3G, 3G+, H+, 4G LTE…) from the Cloud or on premise with bandwidth constraints, latency, and packet loss simulation. This integrated capability allows you to check the response times of your mobile users and load your servers under real world conditions, for no additional cost.

We offer a free 30-day evaluation so that you can try NeoLoad.

Regards,
Hervé

Comment: Yeah, thanks for valuable suggestion, i have got `MonkeyTalk` tool, its an open source tool, Whatever you are listed out through `NeoLoad` except `Network use` MonkeyTalk gives it. I have no idea how NeoLoad works, I am going to check it in trail period.